# How to calculate the probability of "x" things happening out of "n"?

Tags: probability

I am currently studying for my upcoming midterm and I am stumped on this example provided in the slides. Basically here is the question:

> Given 35 computers, what is the probability that more than 10 computers are in use(active)? We are told that each computer is only active 10% of the time. The answer given in the slide is .0004

Here is my following attempt to reproduce that answer:

$$1-{35 \choose 10} \cdot (0.10)^{10} \cdot (0.90)^{25}$$

First I got the probability of exactly 10 computers being active out of 35 and then I subtracted 1 from it to get the probability of more than 10 computers.

EDIT: I have solved this now with the following new work!

1 - (summation of (35 choose k)*0.1^k * 0.9^(35-k) from 0 to 10

Comment: No, that's the probability of having both more and less than 10 but not exactly 10

Comment: Oh..., how can I go about fixing this mistake?

Comment: Oh, nvm I managed to get it. I will create and edit to show my new work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have correctly noted, the probability of exactly 10 being active at any one time is
$${35 \choose 10} \cdot (0.10)^{10} \cdot (0.90)^{25}.$$
More generally, the probability of exactly $k$ being active at any time is
$${35 \choose k} \cdot (0.10)^{k} \cdot (0.90)^{35-k}.$$
Since you want the probability of more than $10$ being active, you want either
$$1-\sum_{k=0}^{10} {35 \choose k} \cdot (0.10)^{k} \cdot (0.90)^{35-k}$$
(that is, one minus the probability of ten or fewer) or
$$\sum_{k=11}^{35} {35 \choose k} \cdot (0.10)^{k} \cdot (0.90)^{35-k}.$$

Comment: Dang it seems I was a bit too late but thank you for answering !

Comment: Glad you figured it out yourself!

Answer (score 1):

The expression you have subtracted from $1$ is the correct computation of the probability that exactly $10$ computers are active. The question asks for the probability that more than $10$ are active, so you should sum the chances that $11, 12, 13, \dots$ are active. As you only expect $3.5$ to be active, these will decrease rapidly.  I would compute the chance that exactly $11$ are active (like you did for $10$), then $12$, and keep going until the chance was small enough that it didn't matter any more.

Comment: Your added work is correct.  You can choose whether to add the probabilities of $0-10$ working and subtract from $1$, or to add the probabilities of $11-35$ working. If you want an exact answer, your approach has fewer terms.  If you want an approximate answer, adding those from $11$ until you get satisfied or tired probably has fewer terms.  Both are good approaches to some problems. Good work.

Answer (score 1):

You have *correctly* identified this count as having a **Binomial Distribution**.

So far, so good.   However, what happened next was not okay.

The complement of having more than $10$ computers active is **not** of having *exactly* 10 computers active.   It is of having $10$ *or less* computers active.

$$\mathsf P(X>10) = 1- \mathsf P(X\leq 10) \\ = 1-\sum_{k=0}^{10} \dbinom{35}{k} 0.10^k~0.90^{35-k}$$

That's a sufficient answer for an exam.   It's a little awkward to calculate the answer.

> $$0.999~575~702~404~549~174~279~490~538~848~808~6$$

---

Alternatively you could use the Normal approximation to Binomial and lookup Z-tables if they are provided.

Comment: The normal approximation is a good point.